# How to read the data from an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JavaScript array like `[{"itemName":"table ","status":"sold"},{"itemName":"chair ","status":"available"}]` (Each time I click on a button on a row of my data, the array size and its values are changed) and I want to read its data and show the values in

```
modal.find('.modal-body input[name="itemname"]').val(itemName);
modal.find('.modal-body input[name="status"]').val(status);
```

I appreciate if anyone can help me to set the data of the array in its equivalent modal.find ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Below

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var data = [{"itemName":"table ","status":"sold"},{"itemName":"chair ","status":"available"}];
        $.each(data, function(index, value){
            $("#result").append(value.itemName + ": " + value.status + '<br>');
        });
    });
</script>  
</head> 
<body>
    <div id="result"></div>
</body>
```

Please support with answered if it helps you, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop through the array and access it you can do it like this:

```js
const items = [{"itemName":"table ","status":"sold"},{"itemName":"chair ","status":"available"}]

items.map(item => {
  modal.find('.modal-body input[name="itemname"]').val(item.itemName);
  modal.find('.modal-body input[name="status"]').val(item.status);
});
```

Comment: This will end up with only the values of the last item in the array, since every iteration it overwrites the previous set value.

Comment: Well, if there were multiple input fields to set values, which wasn't mentioned in the question, they could use the same loop

Comment: They could, but that was indeed not mentioned. Right now the map doesn't make much sense, since you could as well simply get the last element of the array and have the same result. That being said, if you don't do anything with the return value of `.map()`, it makes no sense to use it. (Use `.forEach()` instead.)

Comment: Sure would do that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
data = [{"itemName":"table ","status":"sold"},{"itemName":"chair ","status":"available"}]

modal.find('.modal-body input[name="itemname"]').val(data[0]['itemName']);
modal.find('.modal-body input[name="status"]').val(data[0]['status']);

modal.find('.modal-body input[name="itemname"]').val(data[1]['itemName']);
modal.find('.modal-body input[name="status"]').val(data[1]['status']);
```

```js
data = [{
  "itemName": "table ",
  "status": "sold"
}, {
  "itemName": "chair ",
  "status": "available"
}]
console.log(data[0]['itemName'])
console.log(data[0]['status'])
console.log(data[1]['itemName'])
console.log(data[1]['status'])
//modal.find('.modal-body input[name="itemname"]').val(data[0]['itemName']);
//modal.find('.modal-body input[name="status"]').val(data[0]['status']);

//modal.find('.modal-body input[name="itemname"]').val(data[1]['itemName']);
//modal.find('.modal-body input[name="status"]').val(data[1]['status']);
```

or

```
  a = ''
  b = ''
  for (i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    a += data[i]['itemName'] + ' '
    b += data[i]['status'] + ' '
    modal.find('.modal-body input[name="itemname"]').val(a);
    modal.find('.modal-body input[name="status"]').val(b);
  }
```

```js
data = [{"itemName":"table ","status":"sold"},{"itemName":"chair ","status":"available"}]

  a = ''
  b = ''
  for (i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    a += data[i]['itemName'] + '  '
    b += data[i]['status'] + '  '
    //modal.find('.modal-body input[name="itemname"]').val(a);
    //modal.find('.modal-body input[name="status"]').val(b);
  }
  console.log(a)
  console.log(b)
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'itemName' of undefined. this is the error I see in the console.

Comment: @MinaMRM check my answer

Answer (score 0):

I guess I can help you with that.

For Example:

```js
var example = [
{"itemName":"table ","status":"sold"},
{"itemName":"chair ","status":"available"}];

example.forEach(element=>{
console.log(element.itemName);
console.log(element.status);
});
```

Comment: example.forEach is not a function, this is the error shows me in the console

Comment: @MinaMRM i have made edit to the answer, now you can run it on your browser and the output can be seen here on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are finding the modal with same itemName as you have in the array. If so then the following solution will help.

```
const array = [{"itemName":"table ","status":"sold"},{"itemName":"chair ","status":"available"}]

array.forEach(item => {
  modal.find(`.modal-body input[name=${item.itemName}]`).val(item.itemName);
  modal.find(`.modal-body input[name=${item.status}]`).val(item.status);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It just showed me the last data of the array on my Modal. I mean I can see just chair and available values on my modal

Comment: Have a look at this https://jsfiddle.net/jrm8ead9/1/
If even this doesn't help please share your HTML code.